# Jenkins plugin - referring to global plugin settings in project plugin settings

Tags: java, hudson, jenkins, jelly

I would like to wrote simple hudson plugin. I got stuck on one thing. I would like to be able to use global settings from global.jelly as defaults values for config.jelly.

Is it possible? How can I do this? One more thing - I'm going to have dynamic form in global.jelly (I will use `<f:repeatable>` tag).

Answer (score 2):

When the user submits the global configuration, `configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject json)` is called on your descriptor. Usually you extract your setting from the request and put it into a field in your descriptor, where it will be automatically persisted.

Now define a getter for the setting in your descriptor and use e.g. `<f:textbox default="${descriptor.getSetting()}/>` in the config.jelly to access the global setting.